# What does the (-) in 'abi_x86_32(-)' signify in an ebuild?

Tags: gentoo, emerge

In the process of updating my Gentoo system, I've run into something I don't understand.  Wine is requesting `app-emulation/emul-linux-x86-soundlibs`, which in turn requests `>=media-plugins/alsaequal-0.6-r1[abi_x86_32(-)]`, which then in turn requests `>=media-plugins/caps-plugins-0.9.11[${MULTILIB_USEDEP}]`.  `caps-plugins` turns around and depends on `!<=app-emulation/emul-linux-x86-soundlibs-20130224-r2` and `!app-emulation/emul-linux-x86-soundlibs[-abi_x86_32(-)]`.  Most of these are using (-) to mean something.

What does the trailing `(-)` mean?

Comment: Could it be "atom use defaults" as per `man 5 ebuild` ?

Comment: Aha, that appears to answer the first part. Now to determine how that relates to the second in causing the whole thing to fail an update.

Comment: I guess as a follow-up question 1a: what sets `MULTILIB_USDEP`?

Comment: Yeah, I'm hoping someone else knows.  I've been using Gentoo for awhile, but rarely muck around in the more complicated stuff.  I'm not quite sure how setting `abi_x86_32(-)` is impacting my issue though.  I haven't quite wrapped my head around what it means.

Comment: @illuminÉ, I think I'm going to split this off into two separate questions.  My first question is answered pretty clearly by your comment, so I'll edit this and redefine it as strictly the first part if you'd like to post your comment as an answer.  I'll ask my other questions again with more focus now that I have a better understanding of what's going on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is about the semantics of a `depend atom` (a dependency) specification. In the question you have:

```
>=          | media-plugins/alsaequal-0.6-r1 | [abi_x86_32(-)]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
atom prefix | atom base (category/name-ver.) | [atom USE(atom USE defaults)]    
 operator
```

This is documented in *section 5* of the ebuild [manual](http://dev.gentoo.org/~zmedico/portage/doc/man/ebuild.5.html) (`man 5 ebuild`):

> Atom USE defaults
>
> Beginning  with  EAPI 4, USE dependencies may specify default
>   assumptions about values for flags that may or may not be missing from
>   the  IUSE  of the matched package. Such defaults are specified by
>   immediately following a flag with either (+) or (-). Use (+) to behave
>   as if a missing flag  is present and enabled, or (-) to behave as if
>   it is present and disabled:
>
> ```
> Examples:
>                       media-video/ffmpeg[threads(+)]
>                       media-video/ffmpeg[-threads(-)]
> ```

Accordingly here, this seems to indicate that the ebuild behavior about this abi_x86_32 flag should be to assume that if it is missing, it is present but disabled.